# Android - how to answer Skype/VoIP calls?

Tags: java, android, voip, viber

I'm interested in programatically answering a VoIP call, preferably within the Skype application, using my app's background service. So I would need to be able to detect an incoming Skype call somehow, and then answer it. I've used the ITelephony interface to answer regular calls and this seems to be working on most phones.

Is this even possible? Is there an open-source Skype API for mobile I could use to do this?

Cheers.

EDIT - does anyone know if there's a Viber open source API? It's another VoIP smartphone application that I could work with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Skype is not VoIP. It uses it's own closed protocol.
2. Since Skype protocol is proprietary and no API is available, you can not detect that "a call" is coming.
3. There is no open-source Skype API.

Comment: Skype *is* VoIP -- it does Voice, and it does it over IP.  It might not be a standardised protocol (and I wish it were) but that doesn't make it not VoIP.

Comment: EDIT - do you know if there's a Viber open source API? It's another VoIP smartphone application that I could work with.

Answer (score 3):

It's not viable since Skype is not open source, and any attempt will be just a hack. Skype uses a propietary protocol and a propietary interface. What you can do is use a VOIP library for non Skype communications. A quick search in google revealed some dead projects, so start from there.